# Button inside p:contentFlow not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, contentflow

Following is my code:

```
<p:contentFlow value="#{fileOnDeskViewDlgBacking.filesContentFlowList}" var="row">
<p:panel styleClass="filePanel" >
<p:outputLabel value="#{row.srNo}" />
        <p:panelGrid styleClass="borderless" columns="2">
           <p:graphicImage name="/dashboard/images/file_64px.png"/>

            <p:panelGrid styleClass="borderless" columns="1">
                <p:outputLabel value="(#{row.subject})" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:outputLabel style="color:#3D83B5;" value="Files#{row.date}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/mm/yyy HH:mm" />
        </p:outputLabel>
        <h:panelGrid styleClass="borderless" columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="FileId:" />
            <p:outputLabel styleClass="wrapText" value="#{row.Id}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Description:" />
            <p:outputLabel styleClass="wrapText" value="#{row.description}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Heading:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{row.name}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Priority:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{row.priorityName}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Type:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{row.typeName}" />

            <!-- <p:outputLabel value="Created By:" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{row.createdBy}" /> -->

        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:spacer height="5px" />
        <p:separator />
        <p:commandButton value="#{row.fileId}" action="#{fileOnDeskViewDlgBacking.fileNoting(row.fileId)}" />
    </p:panel>
</p:contentFlow>
```

The problem is here on button `<p:commandButton value="#{row.fileId}" action="#{fileOnDeskViewDlgBacking.fileNoting(row.fileId)}" />` the method does not pass `fileId` and it resolved to null, where as `#{row.fileId}` alwasys give its value.

**MORE**
It do work in `p:dataTable`, there is any problem with the component i think.

Comment: Try to surround your code with h:form tag and add process="@this" to your command button.

Comment: It is in h:form and nothing happening with process="@this"